# Spring @Value and dynamically modifying values at runtime (PlaceholderConfigurerSupport)

Tags: spring

This is a question about customisation of Spring's placeholder resolution in @Value annotations.

We initialise all properties in our app using @Value, normally from servlet context init params, eg:

**web.xml**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>app.some.param</param-name>
    <param-value>SOME_VALUE</param-value>
</context-param>
```

**Class file**

```
@Value("${app.some.param:DEFAULT_VALUE}")
private String myParameter;
```

We actually don't use web.xml, we use Tomcat context files or even specify using vmargs.

What we'd like to support is dynamic changes to these properties at runtime. I want to somehow collect a list of property keys that are used in @Value and which also have a new annotation like @Dynamic. For properties marked as @Dynamic the bean may provide a corresponding setter, to do any re-initialisation when the property is modified.

I would then like to create a service that supports updating the property by key, eg:

```
void setProperty(String key, String value) {
    // find all beans that have @Value and @Dynamic and set field or call setter
    // NB - should support Spring type coercion, eg. string --> integer, boolean, list, etc.
}
```

I've been looking at the source for PlaceholderConfigurerSupport and BeanDefinitionVisitor. It seems I might be able to override PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties and create a custom BeanDefinitionVisitor, but there is quite a lot of code to wade through. I wondered if anyone had looked at this before and found a solution.

I should note that there's more we ultimately want to do. We want to persist changed properties in a backing store, and use these instead of the configuration on startup if they've been modified. In this way we'd have a hierarchy of property sources: default in code, context/property files, peristed config that's been modified. We also want to provide a UI showing a set of all dynamic properties. You get the idea.

Thanks

Comment: Well, usually spring's `app-config.xml` is scanned for modifications and if so: all sessions are passivated and activated and autowirering happens. See i notice the problem that a long-running method asychronously become new values.

Comment: Do you have a link for this feature? I can't find it and not come across. I also don't really want to tear down the whole application context and re-wire it. Only certain properties will support dynamic changes, if they are able without significant change to the app. Others will require a restart. Thanks